In which episode was Ted Baxter offered a job as a game show host?
In which episode of The Mary Tyler Moore Show was Ted Baxter offered a job as a game show host? I remember it had something to do with horse racing as contestants answered questions. He was over the moon at the prospect of being a game show host, and in the end Mr. Grant convinced him to come back to news.

I don't even know what is being asked here.

I believe the OP is possibly asking two questions: 1) What was the fictional TV game show which Ted was being offered as the host; 2) May be asking which episode of the MTMS this happened on. The first being a trivial question IMHO.

It's the 2nd one.  How is it trivial?  I suppose it falls under trivia...

The answer is: Ted's Moment of Glory S6E5. From IMDB: 

Ted is tempted with an offer to host a game show in New York City. Do Mary and Lou really want to see him go? 

